# Functoriality and representability of sending a monoid to its set of invertibles

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, category-theory

There's a function $F: \mathbf{Mon} \to \mathbf{Set}$ sending a monoid to it's set of invertible elements. Since monoid homomorphisms send invertible elements to invertible elements, maybe we can extend $F$ to a functor by defining $Ff : Fm \to Fm'$ as the restriction and corestriction of the underlying monoid homomorphism $f$ to the sets of invertible elements of $m$ and $m'$.

Functor axioms:

$F1_m = 1_{Fm}$ because the identity morphism fixes every element; $F(f\circ g) = Ff \circ Fg$ seems obvious, but i have trouble phrasing it in a concise way.

Representability:

It seems to me like $F$ is represented by $\text{Hom}(\mathbb Z_3, -)$, since such a morphism must send $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to an element whose inverse is $F(2)$, and is uniquely determined by this.

Is this correct, and how can this be phrased more concisely and/or correctly?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? "It seems to me like $F$ is represented by $\text{Hom}(\mathbb Z_3, -)$" - unlikely.

Comment: @markvs To show whether $F$ is a functor, and whether it is representable. Doesn't the collection of functions (for each monoid $M$) sending a morphism $f: \mathbb Z_3 \to M$ to the image of $1$ (alternatively of $2$) define a natural isomorphism between $F$ and $\text{Hom}(\mathbb Z_3, -)$?

Comment: The fact that $F$ is a functor is obvious.  Right?

Comment: @markvs Maybe to you, but i am still beginning to learn about category theory, so i don't feel comfortable with just brushing it off as "obvious" yet.

Comment: You may want to take the definition of a functor and check that all/not all conditions are satisfied. It should not take long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $f \colon M \to N$ a monoid homomorphism, $Ff \colon FM \to FN$ can be defined more precisely as the unique function such that $i_N \circ Ff = f \circ i_M$, where $i_S \colon FS \to S$ is the inclusion. Of course, this only makes sense once you prove that if $u \in FM$, then $f(u) \in FN$.

With this, if $M_1 \stackrel{g} \to M_2 \stackrel{f} \to M_3$ are monoid homomorphisms, we note that $Ff \circ Fg$ is a function with the property that
$$i_{M_3} \circ Ff \circ Fg = f \circ i_{M_2} \circ Fg = f \circ g \circ i_{M_1},$$
but $F(f\circ g)$ is the unique function with $i_{M_3} \circ F(f \circ g) = f \circ g \circ i_{M_1}$, so, in virtue of the uniqueness, $Ff \circ Fg = F(f \circ g)$. Similarly you can prove that $F(\operatorname{id}_M) = \operatorname{id}_{FM}$ for any monoid $M$.

For the representability, you may want to first prove the following fact:

> If $M$ is a monoid, then for every $u \in FM$ there exists a unique monoid homomorphism $f \colon \mathbb Z \to M$ such that $f(1)=u$. (Here, we are considering $\mathbb Z$ as a monoid with the sum).

Thus, for every monoid $M$,
$$\alpha_M \colon \operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{Mon}(\mathbb Z, M) \to FM, \quad f \mapsto f(1).$$
is a bijection.

Finally, prove that $\alpha \colon \operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{Mon}(\mathbb Z,\_) \to F$ is a natural transformation; hence, $F$ *is represented by* $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: You may want to say explicitly that you are looking at the additive monoid (group) structure of $\mathbb{Z}$, since it is also a monoid under multiplication, lest it cause possible confusion.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the observation! I just added it.